# como puedo remplazar un valor de un string y convertirlo en una funcion como + en una sola linea python

Tags: python-3.x

alguien pregunto eso y bueno, se supone que lo debe de hacer en una linea es para que le regrese la suma de los valores que ingrese en una sola linea y la cuestion es que al convertir un input en python se debe de usar la funcion int() la cual esta bastante bien , pero la cuestion es que ¿como convierto un caracter como " " en alguna funcion tipo +

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Te invito a que leas esta [guía sobre cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Tu pregunta es un poco confusa y no entiendo lo que quieres decir. Pon algún ejemplo de código y lo que has intentado, así como qué error te da para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: O sea, si lo que quieres es convertir alguna cadena que tiene una formula como "2+2" y que esta se trasforme en int y te arroje como resultado 4... Usa la función eval() ... Es eso lo que necesitas?? o trata de mejorar la pregunta para poder entenderte mejor

Answer (score 1):

```
print(sum(int(i) for i in input().split(' ')))
```

Por ejemplo, si la entrada es:

5 9 8

Imprime en consola:

22

Otra solución podría ser:

```
print(sum(map(int, input().split(' '))))
```

Esta también imprime el mismo resultado.

Comment: muchas gracias se lo agradezco

Comment: OK, ¿podrías dar tu voto?